# Mock a method or the entire service in the unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

The global structure of my API consists in 3 layers: one for controllers, one for services and one for repository.

I would like to unit test this simplified method of the service layer:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<TEntityDTO> GetAllEntities(SortingOrder orderBy)
{
    var allItems = _unitOfWork.Entity.Get(null, order);
    await foreach (TEntity item in allItems)
    {
        yield return _mapper.Map<TEntityDTO>(item);
    }
}
```

Where `_unitOfWork` is the injection of my `UnitOfWork` class and `orderBy` parameter is defined in this method (to become order) and used in the `Get` method of the repository.

I have 2 options:

1. Mocking _unitOfWork
2. Mocking _unitOfWork.Entity.Get(null, order)

In the first case, I will use the real `Get` method of the repository, then if the test fails either service or repository can be involved. Finally, maybe I'm wrong, it's no more a unit test.

In the second case, unit testing the method consists in validating the foreach loop. Is it really useful?

What do I have to mock?

**UPDATE**
Unit test:

```
public async Task GetAllEntities_FetchEntities_ReturnsCorrectNumberOfEntities<TEntity, TEntityDTO>()
    where TEntity : class, IEntityBase, new()
    where TEntityDTO : class
{
    //Arrange
    var unitOfWork=new Mock<IUnitOfWork<TEntity>>();
    unitOfWork.Setup(u => u.Entity.Get(null, null)).Returns(this.GetAsyncEntities<TEntity>);
    ServiceBase<TEntityDTO, TEntity> service = new ServiceBase<TEntityDTO, TEntity>(unitOfWork.Object, Mapper);
   //Act
    List<TEntityDTO> entities = new List<TEntityDTO>();
    await foreach (var item in service.GetAllEntities(orderBy:SortingOrder.None))
    {
        entities.Add(item);
    }
    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(3, entities.Count);
}
```

Comment: What does your unit test look like right now?

Comment: What is the thing that you're trying to test here?

Comment: Done. @Zohar, that's a part of my interrogation, is it necessary to test?

Comment: Well, I don't see any logic to test here...

Comment: You mean that if there is no logic in the method, no need to test it?

Comment: yes, no point of testing `foreach`... and if it's the mapping you want to test, then test the mappings directly